# UIView animates to the wrong position

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, core-animation

UIView.animate seems to animate to the wrong position

```
card.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(scale), y: CGFloat(scale)).rotated(by: CGFloat(rads))

print("animating to [\(x), \(y)]")
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    card.view.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    card.view.transform = .identity
}, completion: { (suc) in
    card.view.isHidden = true 
    print("view center : \(self.view.center) card center: \(card.view.center)")
})
```

And it does animate to the wrong position. And so does the printing shows:

> animating to [480.0, 234.0]
>
> view center : (160.0, 284.0) card center: (160.0, 284.0)

Comment: Please elaborate your question, What exactly you want?

Comment: I mean, I would like that animating to x, y to be the same in the completion block...

Comment: @HelloimDarius Do you want to animate card view to centre?

Comment: @HelloimDarius I can't reproduce your problem, can you post your current view Hierarchy